# how to add a facebook page latest posts into my wordpress site

Tags: posts, facebook

hi I want to show all the posts of a face-book page in my word press site. I tried "Embedded posts"..but when I give the URL of post it shows the preview as

```
"This Facebook post is no longer available. 
 It may have been removed or the privacy settings of the post may have changed."
```

what should I do for this? any alternative idea?
the code i got for embedded post is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1& appId=231268450376260";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
 <div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Dr.Seenaj" data-width="500"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please paste here all your code about this function. And next take a look at this tutorial: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/display-facebook-feed-wordpress-31436.html

Best regards!

Comment: hi..thanks for ur response sir. the code i get from facebook developer after read ur link is <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDr.Seenaj&amp;width&amp;height=395&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;header=false&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=true&amp;appId=231268450376260" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:395px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>       this shows nothing

Comment: Read once again there is everything what you need: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/